# Programming using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Please i'd like to use prediction techniques in sklearn
I have this file:

```
x | y
1| 1
2| 4
4|16
```

--> prediction techniques must give me this model y=x*x

using this model i can predict the value y of x=3
This is a sample example. In my experiment i use a file with 1000 lines.
Please, how can i transform these lines on codes ?

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
 from sklearn import linear_model  
 X = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 4, 16]]  
 poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2) 
 X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this

```
import numpy as np
from  sklearn import linear_model

X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T**2
y=np.array([1, 4, 16])

model=linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
X_predict=np.array([[3,1]]).T**2
model.predict(X_predict)
```

Comment: array([9., 1.]), please what method i have to use to display the model ?

Comment: print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)  ? Please what mean  .T**2  ?